# QGIS QgsLayerTreeGroup signal "currentLayerChanged"?

Tags: pyqgis

In a pyqgis context, I use the "currentLayerChanged(QgsMapLayer *)" signal of the QgisInterface class to do something when the current layer is changed, but I need now to do the same when I select a group, not a layer. The class QgsLayerTreeGroup derives from QgsLayerTreeNode who has signals reflecting a change in structure, or a change in active/inactive and expanded/collapsed, but no selection signal.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: navigate the hirarchy of the http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html and carefully read: http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/

Comment: The problem is that the signal "currentLayerChanged" of the QgsLayerTreeView class is not triggered when I select a group (NOT a layer).

Comment: QgsLayerTreeView is a QTreeView that is a QAbstractItemView that hase clicked events and so on. I don't think there are masked events in the qgs implementation of the TreeView.

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't get that. Thanks a lot.